# Unable to suppress PowerShell warning

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, deprecation-warning

I am working on a script and I've encountered a command that I could not suppress it's warning.

I tried `-WarningAction SilentlyContinue` and `... | Out-Null`. I even tried to assign the command to a variable

```
$a = *command*
```

with no success.

The command is `New-PSSession`, and I am connecting to Exchange via URI, so I basically load Exchange commands.

PowerShell version is 5.

Comment: I would give it a try and change `$WarningPreference` to something different than 'Continue'. Also, if you want to redirect this stream, you need to `Write-Warning Foo 3> $null`

Comment: What BartekB said. Pipe and assignment operator won't help because they affect the success output stream, not the warning output stream. [Details](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What BartekB suggested worked, thank you.

I would give it a try and change `$WarningPreference` to something different than 'Continue'. Also, if you want to redirect this stream, you need to `Write-Warning Foo 3> $null`